# Tango with Django - IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, django

I have this code, following the Tango with Django tutorial:

manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tango_django.settings")

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

But I get an error:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations rango
File "manage.py", line 8
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
                                                           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I tried tabnanny and got this:

```
$ python -m tabnanny manage.py
'manage.py': Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (<tokenize>, line 8)
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You should Tango with Python before you Tango with Django

Comment: We all got to start somewhere right?

Comment: I am able to resolve these tabs/spaces problems in Sublime Text by "converting indentations to spaces" under the View settings. In the similar question, one user suggested "converting indentations to tabs" and that didn't do the trick for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is no indented block below the `if` condition which ends with `:`. In Python, this is what we call [significant whitespace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3MDc_adVhA).

Indent the content of the `if` block with 4 spaces for example which is [PEP8 compliant](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#code-lay-out):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tango_django.settings")
```

Comment: Thanks @jpic for the quite response. I tried indenting 4 spaces per line, and now a new error pops up that seems related to the models.py. Luckily, I am able to resolve these tabs/spaces problems in Sublime Text by "converting indentations to spaces".

Comment: Maybe close this question and create a new one then ?